# Elliptic Curve Key Agreement - ElGamal

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve

I am trying to generate shared secret for given keys using ECKA-EG agreement, but 
I am failing to do so, I tried to use such code:

```
 KeyAgreement keyAgreement = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH", PROVIDER);
    keyAgreement.init(secretKey);
    BCECPrivateKey ecKey = (BCECPrivateKey) secretKey;
    ECParameterSpec ecSpec = ecKey.getParameters();
    PublicKey pubKey = extractECPublicKey(ecSpec, publicKey);
    keyAgreement.doPhase(pubKey, true);
    return keyAgreement.generateSecret("AES").getEncoded();
```

But the result shared secret is not what I am expecting...

It means that I have some ciphered values from External Machine(shared secret should be ciphered after calculating and sent bakc), the ciphering key is given to me by this server, what is more I have sample shared secret:

```
  Shared Secret =    0x3F33EC720C06043647195589EA8182AC3F7190DAF8CBE2A3972E9DA6FB160CAF
```

and

```
Result = 0x1ACF5F4B5633FA391D3E91CC2E12201F
```

If I hardcode this shared secret to my app the result is ok, so only failing point is generation of Shared Secret, according to spec it should be ECKA-EG.

How should I perform ECKA-EG in java ?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "is not what I am expecting??". Refer to [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry I had too many windows and posted wrong ver.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?